How to add two Jupiter swap transactions

    // First swap transaction (JUP to SOL)
    const quoteResponse1 = await (
      await fetch(
        "https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote?inputMint=JUPyiwrYJFskUPiHa7hkeR8VUtAeFoSYbKedZNsDvCN&outputMint=So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112&amount=100000&slippageBps=50"
      )
    ).json();

    const { swapTransaction: swapTransaction1 } = await (
      await fetch("https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          quoteResponse: quoteResponse1,
          userPublicKey: publicKey?.toString(),
        }),
      })
    ).json();

    // Second swap transaction (SOL to USDC)
    const quoteResponse = await (
      await fetch(
        "https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote?inputMint=So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112&outputMint=EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v&amount=100000000&slippageBps=50"
      )
    ).json();

    const { swapTransaction: swapTransaction2 } = await (
      await fetch("https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          quoteResponse: quoteResponse,
          userPublicKey: publicKey?.toString(),
        }),
      })
    ).json();

    const transaction1 = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(
      Buffer.from(swapTransaction1, "base64")
    );
    const transaction2 = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(
      Buffer.from(swapTransaction2, "base64")
    );



You have a few options,

use jito bundles, to send upto fix transactions at one go
https://jito-labs.gitbook.io/mev/searcher-resources/bundles/how-do-i-send-bundles

Get the swap instructions from both the txs, combine them and then send them as one transaction, but because of the 1232 bytes size limitation of Solana transactions, this might not work


    let tx1Instructions = TransactionMessage.decompile(tx1.message).instructions;
    let tx2Instructions = TransactionMessage.decompile(tx2.message).instructions;

    const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
        payerKey: signer.publicKey,
        recentBlockhash: (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash,
        instructions: [...tx1Instructions, ...tx2Instructions],
    }).compileToV0Message();
 
    let tx = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);
    const txId = await connection.sendTransaction(tx);
    console.log(`https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txId}?cluster=devnet`);

